# Не получается заблокировать публикацию через бота

Tags: python, бот, discord, disnake

Делаю бота для DISCORD на языке python с библиотекой disnake. Возникла необходимость сделать бота, который в каждую новую публикацию будет отправлять сообщение и кнопку для блокировки публикации, но все время не получается и выходит ошибка.

```
    @bot.event
async def on_thread_create(thread):
    if thread.parent_id == IDканала:
        embed = disnake.Embed(
            title="Закрыть обращение",
            description="Вопрос решен - закройте нажав на кнопку ниже."
        )
        button = disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.green, label="Закрыть обращение", custom_id="close_ticket")

        view = disnake.ui.View()
        view.add_item(button)

        message = await thread.send(embed=embed, view=view)

@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    if interaction.data["custom_id"] == 'close_ticket':
        forum_thread = interaction.message
        await forum_thread.edit(locked=True)
```

Ошибка в строке await forum_thread.edit(locked=True), но не понимаю в чем именно.

Comment: Не использовал disnake, но здесь по-моему очевидно, что для закрытия публикации нужно получить саму публикацию. Вы же передаете в функцию **forum_thread** сообщение. Найдите в документации функцию получения самой публикации и далее редактируйте её.

Comment: потому что вы вызываете `edit` у сообщения `interaction.message`, а не у ветки `interaction.message.channel`

Comment: Спасибо большое!